# How would one populate a column with sums of a variable amount of data?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have two sheets. 
OFT Data is rows of values organised by date columns, while Total Counts takes that info and makes it human-readable/interactable.

In Total Counts, there are two named cells with date validation: StartDate & EndDate.
I'd like to add the ability to use those dates to generate a new column that contains the sums of each row's weights for the selected timespan.

---

I've used `ARRAYFORMULA()` to populate a single column based on one date selection, but I'm unsure on how to use multiple.

---

Here's a quick summary of what I'm going for:

We will use data validation to pick two columns (let's just say A & C). This will generate a new column (H) that contains the sums of all values between A & C.

(H1 = A1 + B1 + C1 / H2 = A2 + B2 + C2, etc)

If I select just columns A & B, it'll just be A + B, and if I select A & D, it'll be A + B + C + D.

Is this possible?

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rY9r2GKEtN1EioVG4jwz0rOrNxIB0RurNhVxaC7_rok/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry for the delay; had to make a copy and fix the importdata functions.
Added a link in the description!

Date selection is under "Total Values," and the stuff being summed will be under "OFT Data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your **Sheet1** looks like this:

[image: 0]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&MMULT(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&
 ADDRESS(2,                MATCH(A1, Sheet1!1:1, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(Sheet1!A:A), MATCH(B1, Sheet1!1:1, 0)))*1, 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(A1, Sheet1!1:1, 0)&
             ":A"&MATCH(B1, Sheet1!1:1, 0)))^0), "^0$", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Quick question: is there any way to filter out non-numeric values? I'm getting a #VALUE! error because some of the data is text: "OOS", "-", or "wait".

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(""&MMULT(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&
 ADDRESS(2,                MATCH(A1, Sheet1!1:1, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(Sheet1!A:A), MATCH(B1, Sheet1!1:1, 0)))*1, 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(A1, Sheet1!1:1, 0)&
             ":A"&MATCH(B1, Sheet1!1:1, 0)))^0), "^0$", )))`